# how to remove alternate characters from a php string

Tags: php, string

i have string suppose

```
$str = "abcdefghijklmno";
```

and i want a string like

```
$new_str = "acegikmo";
```

I need a shortest method using any combinations of php functions if possible.

Comment: ^ Well this sounds like you just want some code. Did you tried at least something ?

Comment: str_replace(array('a', 'd', .... 'z'), "", $new_str);

Comment: 1. As you may noticed from the answers your question seems to be unclear if you want to remove every second character in a string or the specific letters e.g. d,e,... 2. You still didn't answered: *Did you tried at least something ?*, but you seem to just want to get your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove every 2nd character of a string with:

```
$str = "abcdefghijklmno";
$str = preg_replace("/(\w)\w/","$1",$str);
```

Example:

```
abcdefghijklmno will become acegikmo
1234567890 will become 13579
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
$string = 'teststring'; //if you want odd places characters then add whitespace at the starting of the string i.e ' teststing'
$array= str_split($string,1);
$new_string = '';
foreach($array $key=>$data){
if($key&1){
            $new_string .= $data;
    }
}
echo $new_string;
```

Comment: @AniketSingh - yes but its subject to that string only. Its known as hardcore coding.

Answer (score 0):

Used the following code

```html
$string = 'abcdefghijklmno';
$new_str = '';
for($i=0;$i<=strlen($string); $i++){
  if($i%2!=0){
    $new_str.=$string[$i-1];
  }
}

echo $new_str;
```

Comment: string is different, this is only example.

Comment: I have answer it as per you asked the question, If you want to do something different then ask question properly.

Comment: if i needed always "acegikmo" then why asked code for it, just stored it in a variable.

Comment: Do you need something like that

Answer (score 0):

If you're running *PHP 5.6* you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$string = "abcdefghijklmno";

$newstring = join("",
                array_filter
                (
                    str_split($string),
                    function($k) { 
                        return ($k % 2 == 0);
                        }, 
                    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
                )
            );
//acegikmo
```

http://ideone.com/HC7eL0